# One Elment Align Top and One Element Align Center

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a question that I have a column and in that column, I have 2 widgets:

1. Container
2. Column

I want this Container to be on the top of the screen and the Column should be in the centre of the screen.

What I have done is as follows:

```
Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10, left: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Profile',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff23b92c),
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xff23b92c),
                  radius: 20,
                  child: Center(
                    child: IconButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        icon: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/question.png',
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Your Name',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100)
                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Email',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100)
                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: Text(
                  'Phone Number',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100)
                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: Text(
                  'Address Line 1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100)
                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Address Line 2',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100)
                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'City, State Zip',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100)
                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Text(
                  'Edit Profile',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color:
                        Color.fromARGB(100, 97, 196, 101).withOpacity(1.0),
                    fontSize: 13,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Text(
                  'Up-to-date name and contact details\nare necessary to receive prizes won.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color:
                        Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100).withOpacity(1.0),
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

With this code, I have achieved the following screenshot
[image: code image]

now what I want to do is that the whole column with the text YOUR NAME, EMAIL, Phone Number etc. should be in the centre and the profile and the question mark should be on the top.

Please help me out how to do this or is there is any other better way other than this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using stack. The first child would be The Container and the second(upper) child would be the Column with mainAlignment to center.

```dart
        Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                child: Text('Your Icons'),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Your name'),
                  Text('Email'),
                  Text('Phone'),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Another way would be using a parent column with expanded first child and spacer as last one

```dart
        Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Text('Your Icons'),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text('Your name'),
                Text('Email'),
                Text('Phone'),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 widgets in your column. and make mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly or spaceBetween to give equal space to all of three widgets. and make the last one as dummy. just like below

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly
  children: [
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
    SizedBox(height: 5),
  ],
)
```

in your case add the root column property `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` and group both the collection top and center widget in `Column()` and add the last widget as dummy like `SizedBox(height:8)`